# Algebraic equation of a specific six-degree polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

During my research, I was analyzing a linear system with characteristic polynomial of six order, $p(x)=x^6+3ax^5+3a^2x^4+a^3x^3 - a^3b_1b_3b_3$. I used Mathematica and it found all roots as the following:

[image]

I was quite impressed since it is not obvious for me how to factor this equation. I am curious how Mathematica find these solutions? What is the algorithm?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 15):

It factors very nicely:
$$p(x)=(x(x+a))^3-a^3b_1b_2b_3$$
So when $p(x)=0$, $x(x+a)$ equals one of the cube roots of $a^3b_1b_2b_3$, and then we can use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Nice. I'd add that the first big clue that this works is the 1, 3, 3, 1 pattern of coefficients in the first four terms.